# How to setup a python extension development enviroment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, cython

I am developing a python extension module with cython, but so far it's not being a good experience. The python I am using to test the extension is actually embedded in another software (blender).

I have to support Linux and windows versions of 32 and 64 bits, for now I am just compiling in 64bits for testing.

The problem is that every time I run Build, the module gets compiled to

`build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\c_fields.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` but my testing folder where I import the module is in another place, so every time, I have to copy and paste it. I guess there are smarter ways of doing it.

I would like to know if there's a way to compile the module straight to my testing folder. so far I am using a .bat script to build the module:

`build64.bat`

```
python setup.py build_ext --plat-name=win-amd64
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your compiler, you can choose the build directory (When using distutils, you can compile using the parameter `build_dir="build"`)

However, this is not a bad practice to compile inplace with the option `--inplace`